# Question about plotting a curve and tangent lines

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coding-style

This is a Mathematica question.

I have a function $y=x^3$. “Fun1” is any point on the curve. At the point Fun1, draw a tangent line at that point to the curve.

At another point where the curve and the tangent intersect I need to mark it with “Fun2”.The area between the segment Fun1Fun2 and the curve should be denoted "A”

Now I need to find at point Fun2, the tangent line, and this tangent intersects the curve again at "Fun3". The area between the segment Fun2Fun3 and the curve should be denoted "B”

I think this is similar to the Tangent Line problem

This is what I did so far.

I considered a point (2,8) for FUN1. Am I supposed to consider both  x and y coordinate? The formula I was given for finding a tangent doesn’t include the y coordinate(f[x0] + f'[x0] (x -x0)). Is something here incorrect? How can I show FUN 2 and find its coordinates to find FUN3?

```
f[x_] := x^3 ;
x0 = 2;
l[x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0);
Plot[{f[x], l[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, 
  Mesh -> {{x0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-1, 15}}, 
  Epilog -> Text["FunOne", {x0, f[x0]} + {1, .1}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this problem by defining the derivative and tangent functions a little differently. I would also work out a good set of intersections of the tangents with the curve before doing any plotting. Like so:

**Basic definitions**

```
f[x_] := x^3;
df[x_] = f'[x];
tan[x_, x0_] := f[x0] + df[x0] (x - x0)
```

**Finding intersection points**

Starting with `x0 = 1.2` based on my knowledge of what `x^3` looks like.

```
With[{x0 = 1.2}, NSolve[tan[x, x0] == f[x], x]]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -2.4}, {x -> 1.2}, {x -> 1.2}}
> ```

So `x1 = -2.4` and it is now used to find `x2`.

```
With[{x1 = -2.4}, NSolve[tan[x, x1] == f[x], x]]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -2.4}, {x -> -2.4}, {x -> 4.8}}
> ```

**Making the plot**

```
Module[{x, pts, names, offsets, ptlbls, arealbls},
  x[0] = 1.2; x[1] = -2.4; x[2] = 4.8;
  pts = {{x[0], f[x[0]]}, {x[1], f[x[1]]}, {x[2], f[x[2]]}};
  names = {"Fun1", "Fun2", "Fun3"};
  offsets = {{10, -10}, {10, -10}, {-15, 3}}; 
  ptlbls = MapThread[Text[#1, Offset[#2, #3]] &, {names, offsets, pts}];
  arealbls = {
    Text["A", Offset[{-20, 2}, (pts[[1]] + pts[[2]])/2]],
    Text["B", Offset[{0, -35}, (pts[[2]] + pts[[3]])/2]]}; 
  Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], tan[x, x[0]], tan[x, x[1]]}, {x, -3, 5},
    Epilog -> {ptlbls, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]}, arealbls}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @QyLn/ I'm glad you find my answer useful. However, you should not ask a new question as a comment to an answer. Questions should focus on a single issue, so you should start ask your question about area in a new post. You can refer to this question or, more specifically, this answer in your new post. Further, as it is posed here, the area question is unclear. Two points do not enclose an area.

Comment: thank you for letting me know!  i will delete my question and make a new question!

Comment: @QyLn. Don't delete this question. It is a perfectly good question. Just ask about the area computation in new question.

Comment: Can I use your code? How can I reference you in my new post?

Comment: @QyLn. Certainly. Just make a reference to my answer by linking you new post to this question. Click on the share button under the question to make a copy of the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You did well, no error. Only x2 is chosen, so that "Fun3" is way down in the -y direction. Choose x0=1 to make it simpler:

```
f[x_] := x^3;
x0 = 1;
l[x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0);
x2 = x /. Solve[l[x] == x^3, x][[1]];
Plot[{f[x], l[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, Mesh -> {{x0, x2}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-15, 15}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["Fun1", {x0, f[x0]} + {1, .1}], 
   Text["Fun2", {x2, f[x2]} + {1, .1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, how can i show point FUN2, on the curve where it intresects?

Comment: Epilog -> Text["Funtwo", {x0, f[x0] == l[x0]} + {1, .1}] i added ths but it doesn't show up in my graph

Comment: From: Solve[l[x] == x^3, x]  you get the x  coordinates of  Fun2 :x2=-2 . Epilog reads now:  {Text["Fun1", {x0, f[x0]} + {1, .1}], 
 Text["Fun2", {x2, x2^3} + {1, .1}]}. I updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MeshFunctions` to find and mark the intersections of the curve with the selected tangent line:

```
ClearAll[f, t]
f[x_] := x^3
t[x0_][x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0)

plot = With[{x0 = 2}, Plot[{f @x , t[x0]@x}, {x, -5, 5},
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-80, 80}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {# &, f @ # - t[x0] @ # &}, 
   Mesh -> {{x0}, {0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize @ Large, Red],
   ClippingStyle -> False]]
```

[image]

and post-process to inject the labels:

```
plot /. Point[x_] :> {Point[x], 
   MapThread[Text[Style[#, 16, Black], #2, {1, -3/2}] &, {{"fun1", "fun2"}, x}]}
```

[image]

Alternatively, combine the two steps in a single step using the option [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) to do the post-processing inside `Plot`:

```
With[{x0 = 2}, Plot[{f @x , t[x0]@x}, {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-80, 80}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, f@# - t[x0]@# &}, Mesh -> {{x0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red],
  ClippingStyle -> False, 
  DisplayFunction -> (Show[# /. Point[x_] :> {Point[x], 
   MapThread[Text[Style[#, 16, Black], #2, {1, -3/2}] &, 
     {{"fun1", "fun2"}, x}]}] &)]]
```

[image]

**Note:** In version 11.3.0 replace `x` in the last line with `x[[;;;;2]]`.

**Update:** We can also inject the labels using the option `MeshStyle`. This old trick (using a function as the `MeshStyle` setting) still works in version 12.1.2:

```
meshStyle = {PointSize[Large], Red, #, 
   If[# === {}, {}, 
     MapThread[Text[Style[#, 16, Black], #2, {1, -3/2}] &, 
        {{"fun1", "fun2"}, #[[1]]}]]} &;

With[{x0 = 2}, Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {# &, f[#] - t[x0][#] &}, Mesh -> {{x0}, {0}}, 
    ClippingStyle -> False,   
    MeshStyle -> meshStyle,
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-80, 80}}, 
    Epilog -> {Orange, InfiniteLine[{x0, f@x0}, {1, f'[x0]}]}]]
```

[image]